# How to bind events of <ion-segment> and <ion-slides> in ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, event-handling, ionic3

I am making an e-commerce app. On my home page i am displaying my products by category. i am using both ion-segment and ion-slides so that user will be able to scroll and select both at a time . it was fine when i had three categories , all were displaying at home but when i increased category other categories are behind screen . categories products are displaying fine but category name is inside and not visible. i want to scroll both category name and products displayed at same time on screen. that is i want to get the active segment visible on the screen, when the segment is off screen .thanks in advance :-)
[image: here is the problem]

```
<ion-content>
<ion-segment color="dark" [(ngModel)]="tabs" style="width:640px;">
    <ion-segment-button *ngFor="let i of productcategory" (click)="selectTab(i)" value="{{i.inc}}" >{{i.category_name}}</ion-segment-button>
    <div id="slide" class="slide"></div>
</ion-segment>

<ion-slides #pageSlider (ionSlideWillChange)="changeWillSlide($event)">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let i of productcategory">

            <ion-list>
                    <div *ngFor="let pr of products; let i=index" text-wrap class="swipe-tabs">

                            <div class="swipe-tabs-1">  
                                    <img src="http://example.com/{{pr.tbl_product_image}}" />
                                    <button ion-button (click)="removefromcart(pr,i)">-</button>
                                    <button ion-button color="light" *ngIf="check">{{quan[i]}}</button>
                                    <button ion-button color="light" *ngIf="!check">0</button>
                                    <button ion-button (click)="addToCart(pr,i)">+</button>
                                </div>
                        <div class="swipe-tabs-2">
                            <h2>{{pr.tbl_product_name}} </h2>

                            <ion-list  radio-group  >
                                <ion-item *ngFor="let p of pr.pricevariant; let j=index;">
                                    <ion-label>{{p.weight}} &nbsp; &nbsp; <span class="colr-red">₹ {{p.dprice}}</span></ion-label>
                                    <ion-radio  [value]="p.weight" (ionSelect)="getdata(pr,p,i,j)" ></ion-radio>                                
                                </ion-item>
                            </ion-list>
                        </div>
                        <div class="border-hr"></div>
                    </div>

                </ion-list> 
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by making a content in header and adjusting some events during sliding:-

```
<ion-header>
<ion-content #scroll scrollX="true" scrollY="true" style="height: 50px;">
    <ion-segment class="SwipedTabs-tabs">
        <ion-segment-button *ngFor='let tab of tabs ; let i = index ' value="IngoreMe" (click)="selectTab(i)" [ngClass]='{ "SwipedTabs-activeTab" : ( this.SwipedTabsSlider  && ( this.SwipedTabsSlider.getActiveIndex() === i || (  tabs.length -1 === i&& this.SwipedTabsSlider.isEnd()))) }'
            [ngStyle]="{'width.px': (this.tabElementWidth_px)}">
            {{tab}}
        </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
    <!-- here is our dynamic line  "indicator"-->
    <div id='indicator' class="SwipedTabs-indicatorSegment" [ngStyle]="{'width.px': (this.tabElementWidth_px)}"></div>
</ion-content>
```

```
<ion-slides #SwipedTabsSlider (ionSlideDrag)="animateIndicator($event)" (ionSlideWillChange)="updateIndicatorPosition()" (ionSlideDidChange)="updateIndicatorPosition()" (pan)="updateIndicatorPosition()" [pager]="false">
```

In typescript:-

```
    this.tabs=["SNACKS","SWEETS","NAMKKEN","BAKERY","MISC","ETC"]; 

 selectTab(index) {
this.SwipedTabsIndicator.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d('+(100*index)+'%,0,0)';
 this.scroll.scrollTo(index*this.tabElementWidth_px,0,500);
this.SwipedTabsSlider.slideTo(index, 500);}

updateIndicatorPosition() {
this.scroll.scrollTo(this.SwipedTabsSlider.getActiveIndex()*this.tabElementWidth_px,0,200);

  // this condition is to avoid passing to incorrect index
if( this.SwipedTabsSlider.length()> this.SwipedTabsSlider.getActiveIndex())
{
  this.SwipedTabsIndicator.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d('+(this.SwipedTabsSlider.getActiveIndex() * 100)+'%,0,0)';
}
this.j=this.SwipedTabsSlider.getActiveIndex();
}
```

And in css:

```
page-home {
.segment-ios .segment-button {
    overflow: inherit !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid white !important;
    width: auto !important;
}
.SwipedTabs-indicatorSegment {
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s all;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s all;
    -o-transition: 0.3s all;
    transition: 0.3s all;
    transform-origin: top 0 left 0;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
    background-color: white !important;
}
.SwipedTabs-tabs ion-segment-button {
    border: none !important;
    color: black!important;
    background-color: blue!important;
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
}
.SwipedTabs-tabs ion-segment-button.SwipedTabs-activeTab {
    color: white !important;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.SwipedTabs-tabs {
    width: fit-content !important;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #e6e6e6 !important;
}
.scroll-content {
    display: flex;
    left: -3px;
    right: 0;
    top: 3px;
}
.swiper-container {
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
scroll-content {
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-bottom: -297px;
}
.SwipedTabs-tabs ion-segment-button {
    color: #fff !important;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

}

Comment: hi i am using your code then i am getting error **  [ts] Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Segment'. ** 
this.SwipedTabsIndicator.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d('+(100*index)+'%,0,0)';

Answer (score 1):

You can achive it with below code. I have used ionic 4:

// tab.page.html

```
<ion-header  >
 <!-- Scrollable Segment -->
 <ion-toolbar class="less-height" color="primary">
    <ion-segment scrollable mode="md" (ionChange)="segmentChanged(segment)" [(ngModel)]="segment" >
        <ion-segment-button mode="md" id="seg-1" value="0">
          <p>Description</p>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button mode="md" id="seg-2" value="1">
          <p>Interconnections</p>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button mode="md" id="seg-3" value="2">
          <p>Declensions</p>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button mode="md" id="seg-4" value="3">
          <p>Phraseologisms</p>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button mode="md" id="seg-5" value="4">
          <p>Etymology</p>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button mode="md" id="seg-6" value="5">
          <p>Analysis</p>
        </ion-segment-button>
      </ion-segment>
</ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-slides (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged()" class="word-slides">
        <ion-slide>
          <p>Slide 1</p>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <p>Slide 2</p>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <p>Slide 3</p>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <p>Slide 4</p>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <p>Slide 5</p>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <p>Slide 6</p>
        </ion-slide>
      </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

// tab.page.ts

```
 @ViewChild(IonSlides) slider: IonSlides;
  segment = 0;
  constructor() {}
async segmentChanged(event) {
  await this.slider.slideTo(this.segment);
  this.slider.update();
}
async slideChanged() {
  this.segment = await this.slider.getActiveIndex();
  this.focusSegment(this.segment+1);
}

focusSegment(segmentId) {
  document.getElementById('seg-'+segmentId).scrollIntoView({ 
    behavior: 'smooth',
    block: 'center',
    inline: 'center'
  });
}
```